# Почему не отображаются цвета в программе opengl + shader?

Tags: c, opengl, шейдеры

Вот код, пробую два варианта вывода вершин с цветом, а цвет не отображается.

```
#include "gl_core_4_3.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "gl.h"

int width = 1920;
int height = 1080;
float view[4 * 4];
GLuint program;
// perspective ( 45.0f, aspect , 0.1f, 100.0f );
//
void set_ortho ( )
{
    glViewport ( 0, 0, width, height );
    float ratio;
    ratio = width / height;
//  ortho ( &view[0], -ratio, ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f );
//  ortho ( &view[0], -1.0, 1.0, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f );
//  ortho ( &view[0], -1.0, 1.0, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f );
//  ortho ( &view[0], 0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0.0f, 1.0f );
}
void set_shader ( )
{
    const char *vshader = 
        "#version 430\n"
        "layout ( location = 0 ) in vec3 position;\n"
        "layout ( location = 1 ) in vec3 color;\n"
        "uniform mat4 transform;\n"
        "out vec3 v_color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = transform * vec4 ( position, 1.0f );\n"
        "v_color = color;\n"
        "}\n";
    const char *fshader =
        "#version 430\n"
        "in vec3 color;\n"
        "out vec4 fcolor;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "fcolor = vec4 ( color, 1.0f );\n"
        "}\n";
    program = load_program ( vshader, fshader );
}
void framebuffer_size_cb ( GLFWwindow *win, int width, int height )
{
    glViewport ( 0, 0, width, height );
}
void key_cb ( GLFWwindow *win, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods )
{
    if ( key == GLFW_KEY_Q && action == GLFW_PRESS ) exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
void draw ( )
{
    glUseProgram ( program );
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation ( program, "transform" );
    float transform[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    double time = glfwGetTime ( );
    transform[0] = 2.0f * sin ( time );
    transform[5] = 2.0f * cos ( time );
    //glUniformMatrix4fv ( loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0] );
    glUniformMatrix4fv ( loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &transform[0] );

#if 0
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f
    };
    float colors[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    GLuint vbo[2];
    GLuint vao;
    glGenBuffers ( 2, &vbo[0] );
    GLuint posbuf = vbo[0];
    GLuint colbuf = vbo[1];
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posbuf );
    glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof ( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colbuf );
    glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof ( colors ), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glGenVertexArrays ( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray ( vao );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posbuf );
    glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL );
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colbuf );
    glVertexAttribPointer ( 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL );
    glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
#endif
#if 1
    static float vertices[] = {
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    GLuint vbo, vao;
    glGenVertexArrays ( 1, &vao );
    glGenBuffers ( 1, &vbo );
    glBindVertexArray ( vao );
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
    glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof ( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof ( float ), (void *) 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
    glVertexAttribPointer ( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof ( float ), (void *) (3 * sizeof ( float )) );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 1 );
    glBindVertexArray ( vao );
    glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

#endif
}
int main ( )
{
    if ( !glfwInit ( ) ) return -1;
    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4 );
    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );
    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    if ( ogl_LoadFunctions( ) == ogl_LOAD_FAILED ) {
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow ( width, height, "title", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent ( window );
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback ( window, framebuffer_size_cb );
    glfwSetKeyCallback ( window, key_cb );
    glfwShowWindow ( window );
    set_ortho ( );
    set_shader ( );
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose ( window ) ) {
        glClearColor ( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
        glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        draw ( );
        glfwSwapBuffers ( window );
        glfwPollEvents ( );
    }
}
```

Comment: *"цвет не отображается"* А что отображается?

Comment: Не уверен что ошибка только в этом, проверить не могу, но у вас в вершинном шейдере выходная переменная цвета одно имя имеет, а входная во фрагментном другое

Comment: установил такую же переменную во фрагментном шейдере и всё заработало, спасибо. А то я реальне не понимал в чём проблема.

Comment: только рисует одним цветом, красным.

Comment: Но в другом месте, рисуется нормально, спасибо.